# AngularJs/webAPI: recieving null in the parameter of webAPI

Tags: c#, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am using AngularJS and I am trying to send in a json from my service to the webAPI controller. When I send via I recieve null in the parameter in webApi function.

My function service is:

```
angular.module('productsApp')
    .service('ProductDetailService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var urlBase = "/api/productdetail";

        this.Salvar = function (product) {
            var mydata = JSON.stringify(product);
            debugger;

            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: urlBase + "/salvar/" + mydata,
                data: mydata,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });
        };
    }]);
```

my code in the webAPI is:

```
public class ProductDetailController : BaseController
{
    [Route("api/productdetail/salvar/{item}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool Salvar(string item)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

my app.js is:

```
var app = angular.module('productsApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller: 'ProductController',
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/Html/ProductList.html'
    }).
    when('/testprice', {
        controller: 'ProductController',
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/Html/ProductDetail.html'
    }).
    when('/editar/1', {
        controller: 'ProductController',
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/Html/ProductDetail.html'
    }).
    when('/api/productdetail/salvar/*', {
        controller: 'ProductDetailController',
        templateUrl: '/Scripts/App/Html/ProductDetail.html'
    })
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

}]);
```

The problem in the service is when I am adding to type `data: something` in  I am recieving in the webService null and I have to add my data in the complet uri, something like:

`http//.../api/productdetail/salvar/{mydata}`

using it, it is working.

what is wrong?

Comment: What is the value of mydata when the $http invokes the service?

Comment: it is a product class which I convert it to JSON.stringfly

Comment: Nope. It won't work then, since your parameter is a string type in your controller. It would always be null.

Comment: @Turbulence Wrong, you can url-encode a json and send as part of the query string. It's a bad idea, but sometimes you need to do so to cover som edge cases...

Comment: @MatiasFidemraizer - Thanks for the info. Let me edit the comment.

Comment: @Turbulence No problem!! :D

Comment: yes true, i did it as you comment uncoding url and encoding in base64. it could be interesting to recieve it in the webAPI automatically decoded, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to receive plain text from HTTP/POST body you need to apply `[FromBody]` attribute to controller action's input parameter:

```
[Route("api/productdetail/salvar")]
[HttpPost]
public bool Salvar([FromBody] string item)
{
    return true;
}
```

While you can go this way, WebAPI expects you to design a DTO and receive POST data using a DTO instance (WebAPI deserializes the JSON into the parameter based on its type):

```
[Route("api/productdetail/salvar")]
[HttpPost]
public bool Salvar(MyData item)
{
    return true;
}
```

`MyData`might look like this:

```
public class MyData
{
     public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And your Angular app should send a JSON like this: `{ "Text": "hello world" }`.

Finally, WebAPI enforces RESTful API development and your route is RPC-style. You should rename it to `api/product/details` and POST data to this resource URI. Otherwise, you're not designing a RESTful API!

Remember that REST loves using HTTP verbs to express actions:

- POST is *create*.
- PUT is *update*.
- GET is *get all, get by pages or get by id*.
- DELETE is *delete by id, range, whatever*.
- ...

In summary, don't put verbs in resource URIs but use HTTP verbs to express what to do against your exposed resources.

Comment: It is working fine. Just a question. Is it possible to convert in javascript to Base4 and in the parameter of converted it to the dto mydata automatically decoded from base64?

Comment: @David First part is done using [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa), the other part would be harder, because you would need to implement a custom parameter binding... Why you need to send base64-encoded...?

Comment: well maybe I am thinking in the old suystems which we needed security, I dont know if it is necessary now

Comment: @David Base64 provides no security. It's used to avoid special characters when sending strings over the wire, but you need to pay attention to the fact that a Base64 increases the amount of data to send/receive. Use HTTPS to secure client-server data exchange!

Comment: how can i implement the decode the information before to recieve the dto as parameter? maybe using some attribute?

Comment: @David Look for custom http parameter binding on WebAPI docs. You'll need to provide a `IHttpParameterBinding` implementation and configure it in `HttpConfiguration`. BTW, ask a new question. Comments are here to resolve current answer's content issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Just Food For Thought that got me. If you have a property that is being set to an invalid type like a string being set to an object in json. The api will not translate anything and you will get a null.